I want the model to generate an exact number of tokens, no more, no less
Are there any tips or best practices to achieve this? I have tried few-shot prompting are there any open source models which can perform this? I have tried few-shot prompting it was not giving best results. Thank you in advance

llama.cpp allows the output of the language model to be restricted so as to conform to a given grammar: https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp/blob/master/grammars/README.md - it should be possible to use as grammar a fixed number of characters (characters, not tokens). But there is no guarantee that the output will be of high quality. E.g. for short sequences I would expect the output to simply be truncated mid-sentence.
